# Inject a merge commit with Git

Tags: git, svn, merge

I have a Git repository that was converted from SVN.

Now I have some unmerged branches in Git but I know that they have been merged to the SVN trunk (I guess the reason is that by the time the branches were merged, SVN didn't support the svn:mergeinfo property). However, from the commit messages I know the commit (on trunk/master) in which the branch was merged.

Is there a way to inject a merge commit in Git (e.g. using filter-branch) so that these branches appear fully merged also in the Git world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this was very helpful. After searching again with the right terms, I have found the following solution:

1. Get all remote branches: `for branch in $(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' | egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$'); do     git branch --track "${branch##*remotes/origin/}" "$branch"; done`
2. Add additional parent to merge commits: `git replace --graft <merge commit> $(git show --pretty=%P <merge commit> | head -1)  <additional parent>`
3. Rewrite history: `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`
4. Push changes to remote: `git push -f --all; git push -f --tags`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes, but it's painful".

The least painful method to deal with this is to use `git replace` to build up the grafted graph you would like to have.  Then, if you want this to become permanent, use one final no-operation-style `git filter-branch` to make the replacements permanent.  Because `git replace` simply writes *new* objects (which you can tweak or remove if you get them wrong) that you normally view in place of *existing* objects, you can take however many steps it takes to get it right.  If you have multiple merges to fake up, this will be a lot less painful.

Note that once you make replacements permanent, the hash IDs will all change, so that the final Git repository no longer matches up with what you get from a fresh conversion.